# Several checkstyle reports in jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, checkstyle

Is it possible to have **several** Checkstyle reports in one configuration?

Let's say I want to check the code with one set of rules, and tests - with another. After that I have two xml-reports but only one `Publish Checkstyle analysis results` is available.

Am I missing something or it is just impossible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you tick the `Publish Checkstyle analysis results` checkbox, a text input box should appear.  Assuming that you have, for example, `target/checkstyle-code.xml` and `target/checkstyle-tests.xml` files as the result of your two separate Checkstyle runs, then you can enter `target/checkstyle-*.xml` and the results from both of your Checkstyle results will be aggregated into one Jenkins report.

Comment: is there a possibility to not aggregate those results into 1 checkstyle graph, but have 2 checkstyle graphs - one for each checkstyle-xml-files? i have got a checkstyle-php.xml and a checkstyle-javascript.xml and would prefer to be able to visualize each separately.

Comment: @mostwanted have you found out how to get 2 different checkstyle graphs?